# How do I use a variable that is inside a class of one file in another file?

Tags: python, tkinter, import, attributeerror

I am trying out a Tkinter project that allows users to fill in a form. The file name with the variable (cur_user) which I need is named login.py and the variable is found in the class Login_Window and under a function below. I used "from login import Login_Window" and called the function with Login_Window.cur_user but it gives me an error saying that (type object 'Login_Window' has no attribute 'cur_user'). How do I solve this?

```
def login(self):
        global cur_user
        if self.txtuser.get() == "" or self.txtpass.get() == "":
            messagebox.showerror("Required", "Please enter username and password")

    else:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="assessment", database="sys")
        cur = conn.cursor()

        query = ("select userID from iadata where username=%s")
        value = (self.user_var.get(),)
        cur.execute(query,value)
        row= cur.fetchone()
        cur_user=row[0]
        # print(cur_user)
```

Comment: Could you provide the full code for a minimum reproducible example? And if possible the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

> *How do I use a variable that is inside a class of one file in another file?*

As the question stands, the answer is not that complicated:

```
# module.py
class Values: # In this case the class is used in a way similar to a namespace
    variable = 42

# main.py
import module
print(module.Values.variable) # 42
```